How do unitarians come to terms with the phrase God used to refer to Himself when He initiated creation of the universe?
This question is addressed to non-trinitarian who believe that God is a single being and not made up of several beings. How do you come to terms with these truths as exposed in the book of Genesis.
1. God calls out other beings who are co-creators using the phrase us
Genesis 1:26

Then God said, “Let us make mankind in our image, in our likeness, so that they may rule over the fish in the sea and the birds in the sky, over the livestock and all the wild animals, and over all the creatures that move along the ground.”

The statement above means that the other beings who are being requested to create or make alongside God have the power or are able to create or make which makes them co-creators.
2. God acknowledges that mankind have become like him but uses the phrase us to refer to Himself for a second time
Genesis 3:5

For God knows that when you eat from it your eyes will be opened, and you will be like God, knowing good and evil.

Pay attention to the statement be like God in the verse above and compare to whats being said below.
Genesis 3:22

And the LORD God said, “The man has now become like one of us, knowing good and evil. He must not be allowed to reach out his hand and take also from the tree of life and eat, and live forever.”

God is confirming that man has become like Him but confirms one more time that he is a plural entity by stating that man has become like one of us. In the previous verse the speaker uses the phrase you will become like God, but God uses the term us to refer to Himself which in some way proves trinitarianism as the true doctrine, how do non-trinitarians respond to these truths?
This is because the us cannot refer to angels because angels cannot form, make or create man out of the dust otherwise fallen angels would have created man out of the elements of other planets since the breath of life originates only from God.

Creation is an act of God alone, by which, for his own glory, he brought into existence everything in the universe that never before existed.


The question should make the point that 'us' does not refer to other heavenly spirit beings (angelic in nature) as the existence of such is not revealed until Genesis 3, when the existence of the serpentine spirit is revealed. Thus 'us' is a matter of the only revealed existence capable of Creation - Deity.

@NigelJ, simple angels cannot make or create only God can do that

Indeed, and I think the question needs to state the proof-texts of that truth within the body of the question, as it is relevant. At present, the question lacks that degree of clarity and detail.

@NigelJ. Job 38:4-7 “Where were you when I laid the foundations of the earth? ... When the morning stars sang together, And all the sons of God shouted for joy?"
"Morning stars" and "sons of God" appear to be references to angels. (One could debate this, of course.) If they sang and shouted when the Earth was created, and according to Genesis 1 the Earth was created before humans, then the angels must have been created before humans.

@depperm, thanks for the correction, the actual verse is Genesis 3:5

There is a long discussion of the maybe-not-so-plural Elohim (not only) on Wikipedia. Perhaps this could also be on https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/ because it concerns foremost how we understand the text and only then what conclusions we draw.

Even for Trinitarians, "us" doesn't have to mean the 3 Persons of the Trinity, but the Biblical notion of The Divine Council.  This ANE background solves the "problem" posed by a few other verses as well such as the "sons of God" in Gen 6, Job 1-2, Deut 32:8, Ps 8, Ps 82, etc.

Judeo-Christian mystics argued that there is a distinction between creation of an ephemeral/mortal and a creature with a divine spirit.  The argument is that humans were never supposed to know their mortality, however the act of knowing itself is also the salvation we need to gain the Holy Spirit, and be truly "like" Elohim.

Proverbs 8:22-31 (NIV):

22 The Lord created me as the first of his works, before his acts of long ago.


23 I was formed a long, long time ago.
I was formed at the very beginning, when the world was created.


24 Before there were any oceans, I was born. It was before there were springs flowing with water.


25 Before the mountains were settled in place, I was born. Before there were any hills, I was born.


26 It happened before the Lord made the world and its fields. It was before he made the dust of the earth.


27 I was there when he set the heavens in place. When he marked out the place where the sky meets the sea, I was there.


28 That was when he put the clouds above.     It was when he fixed the ocean springs in place.


29 It was when he set limits for the sea     so that the waters had to obey his command. When the Lord marked out the foundations of the earth, I was there.


30 I was constantly at his side. I was filled with delight day after day. I was always happy to be with him.


31 His whole world filled me with joy.     I took delight in all human beings. (Proverbs 8:22-31 NIV)

Believer's Bible Commentary:

8:30a His activity in creation. Here we learn that the Lord Jesus was the active Agent in creation. The NKJV correctly renders the first part of verse 30, “Then I was beside Him as a master craftsman….” This agrees, of course, with John 1:3; Colossians 1:16; and Hebrews 1:2.

This is a sampling of various Commentaries as to who the Master Worker was.
If Jesus was the master Worker, this would explain who God was speaking to.

I will preface this by noting that I think that any answer to this question is speculative; it’s not something directly addressed by scripture and left for us to ponder. But it is an interesting question.
The best answer that I have found for this is rooted both in Judaism and the Early Church. Namely: by identifying the Son with the Light created on the first day, and as the Wisdom of God in Proverbs 8. The light and wisdom are one and the same. “Us” then both includes Christ and does so without any need to reference the non-biblical concept of the Trinity.
Within Judaism, the first light has long been associated with the Messiah. For example, see Yalkut Shimoni 499:

“Before the world was created, Hashem created the soul of Moshiach. It
shone very brightly, and is hinted to in the verse: “And Hashem saw
the light, that it was good.” The forces of evil also saw this light,
and asked Hashem, “Whose light is this?” Hashem answered, “This is the
king who will defeat all of you in the End of Days.” The forces of
evil then fell on the ground in fear before the soul of Moshiach.
Hashem then asked Moshiach, “It is destined that you will suffer
greatly. Are you willing to accept this suffering?” Moshiach answered,
“If you agree that in the Days of Moshiach everyone will live again
and even those who were meant to be born will come to life — upon
these conditions I happily accept the suffering.” And when the time
for Redemption comes, Avraham, Yitzchak and Yaakov will come to
Moshiach and say, “Perhaps you have bad feeling towards the Jews who
sinned, and therefore caused you to suffer. Maybe you don’t want them
to have a share in the joys of Geulah?” And Moshiach will answer them,
“But all my suffering was only for their sake! Of course I want them
to have a share in the Geulah!” And our Avos will answer him,
“Moshiach, you have comforted us!”

Likewise, many of the Early Church Fathers identified the Son as the Wisdom of God in Proverbs 8. For example, Justin Martyr quotes/paraphrases Proverbs 8 in chapter 61 of his Dialogue with Trypho:

“I shall give you another testimony, my friends,” said I, “from the
Scriptures, that God begat before all creatures a Beginning, [who was]
a certain rational power [proceeding] from Himself, who is called by
the Holy Spirit, now the Glory of the Lord, now the Son, again Wisdom,
again an Angel, then God, and then Lord and Logos; and on another
occasion He calls Himself Captain, when He appeared in human form to
Joshua the son of Nave (Nun). For He can be called by all those names,
since He ministers to the Father’s will, and since He was begotten of
the Father by an act of will; just as we see happening among
ourselves: for when we give out some word, we beget the word; yet not
by abscission, so as to lessen the word [which remains] in us, when we
give it out: and just as we see also happening in the case of a fire,
which is not lessened when it has kindled [another], but remains the
same; and that which has been kindled by it likewise appears to exist
by itself, not diminishing that from which it was kindled. The Word of
Wisdom, who is Himself this God begotten of the Father of all things,
and Word, and Wisdom, and Power, and the Glory of the Begetter, will
bear evidence to me, when He speaks by Solomon the following: ‘If I
shall declare to you what happens daily, I shall call to mind events
from everlasting, and review them. The Lord made me the beginning of
His ways for His works. From everlasting He established me in the
beginning, before He had made the earth, and before He had made the
deeps, before the springs of the waters had issued forth, before the
mountains had been established. Before all the hills He begets me. God
made the country, and the desert, and the highest inhabited places
under the sky. When He made ready the heavens, I was along with Him,
and when He set up His throne on the winds: when He made the high
clouds strong, and the springs of the deep safe, when He made the
foundations of the earth, I was with Him arranging. I was that in
which He rejoiced; daily and at all times I delighted in His
countenance, because He delighted in the finishing of the habitable
world, and delighted in the sons of men. Now, therefore, O son, hear
me. Blessed is the man who shall listen to me, and the mortal who
shall keep my ways, watching daily at my doors, observing the posts of
my ingoings. For my outgoings are the outgoings of life, and [my] will
has been prepared by the Lord. But they who sin against me, trespass
against their own souls; and they who hate me love death.’

Within scripture itself, Jesus is referred to as Light and as the Wisdom of God:
John 1:3-4

In him was life, and that life was the light of all mankind. 5 The
light shines in the darkness, and the darkness has not overcome it.

John 1:9

The true light that gives light to everyone was coming into the world.

John 8:12

When Jesus spoke again to the people, he said, “I am the light of the
world. Whoever follows me will never walk in darkness, but will have
the light of life.”

John 12:36

Believe in the light while you have the light, so that you may become
children of light.” When he had finished speaking, Jesus left and hid
himself from them.

Revelation 21:23-24

The city does not need the sun or the moon to shine on it, for the
glory of God gives it light, and the Lamb is its lamp. The nations
will walk by its light, and the kings of the earth will bring their
splendor into it.

1 Corinthians 1:23-24

but we preach Christ crucified: a stumbling block to Jews and
foolishness to Gentiles, 24 but to those whom God has called, both
Jews and Greeks, Christ the power of God and the wisdom of God.

So then, Christ is the light and wisdom of God - the first of creation. He was present with God in the beginning and it was through him, God’s wisdom, that all else was created.

The book of Hebrews mentions a priest who is without beginning or end of days, without a father and a mother, resembling the Son of God. If this entity is Jesus then how is he a created being?

I don’t see a conflict. The answer is in the verse: “resembling the Son of God.” Surely even a Trinitarian recognizes God as the Father of the Son; hence he is called “Son.” So when the verse speaks of not having a mother or father, this is not excluding God who is the Father of all - and especially of “the Son.” His creation also precedes the heavens - by which time is measured. Rather, he is the measure- for his was the light of the “days” in Genesis 1

But he cannot resemble the Son of God for the Son of God is One

There is a difference between Son of God who is unique and sons of God who are angels.

Israel is also referred to as the firstborn Son of God. Other verses refer to Christ as “one like a Son of Man.” The “like” doesn’t mean he isn’t a Son of Man in this case.

I'll answer from the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints POV.
Most answers to these questions can be answered from the beginning of Plan of Salvation (the first quote for each point will be from this page)

God calls out other beings who are co-creators using the phrase us

Before we were born on earth, we lived with our heavenly parents as Their spirit children. At a council with all of His children, Heavenly Father presented a plan, known as the “plan of salvation” or “the great plan of happiness.”
...
We are on earth because we chose to follow Heavenly Father’s plan. One significant purpose of mortality is to gain a physical body.

Spirits were part of the council in heaven when God presented this plan.  In Moses 2:26-27 it clarifies at least one person who God is speaking to:

26 And I, God, said unto mine Only Begotten, which was with me from the beginning: Let us make man in our image, after our likeness; and it was so. And I, God, said: Let them have dominion over the fishes of the sea, and over the fowl of the air, and over the cattle, and over all the earth, and over every creeping thing that creepeth upon the earth.
27 And I, God, created man in mine own image, in the image of mine Only Begotten created I him; male and female created I them.

Abraham 4:26-27

26 And the Gods took counsel among themselves and said: Let us go down and form man in our image, after our likeness; and we will give them dominion over the fish of the sea, and over the fowl of the air, and over the cattle, and over all the earth, and over every creeping thing that creepeth upon the earth.
27 So the Gods went down to organize man in their own image, in the image of the Gods to form they him, male and female to form they them.

Suggests that some of the spirits helped with at least the spiritual creation, as all things were were created spiritually before they were created physically1, but not all the details of the Creation have been revealed (during the Millennium more will be revealed)2

God acknowledges that mankind have become like him but uses the phrase us to refer to Himself for a second time

Earthly trials are part of mortality and can help us grow to be more like our Heavenly Father.
...
Also essential to God’s plan is agency, or the ability to choose.

Earthly trials exist because of the veil

a God-given forgetfulness that blocks people’s memories of the premortal existence.

In addition to the veil Adam and Eve were initially innocent, not understanding good and evil and having neither joy nor misery.3 By partaking of the fruit of the tree of knowledge of good and evil (which they were commanded not to partake), they became like God or the spirits with Him who do/did not have a veil and are not in a state of innocence, in that they then knew the difference between good and evil.


There are multiple books, chapters, and talks on this subject. Diving too far into any one subject would make this answer massive. I attempted to address the main points. Feel free to look at some of the other sources/related topics:

Gospel Topics: Premortality
Gospel Topics: Creation
Jesus the Christ, chapter 2: Preexistence and Foreordination of the Christ
The Creation, Doctrines of the Gospel
The Fall, Doctrines of the Gospel Student Manual
Gospel Topics: Fall of Adam and Eve
The Origin of Man, 1909, First Presidency
Preach My Gospel, Chapter 3, Lesson 2: Heavenly Father's Plan of Salvation
Seminary Old Testament: The Plan of Salvation
Gospel Principles, first 6 chapters

1 Moses 3:5
2 D&C 101:32-34, 2 Nephi 27:7, 10
3 2 Nephi 2:23, Moses 5:11

Upvoted for the resourceful answer and  detailed explanation.

Honestly, I m not so sure LDS count as non-trinitarian in the sense of the question. (In fact, the title was changed to unitarian, which, I'd say,  is clearly not what LDS are).

@kutschkem LDS is more unitarian than trinitarian from my understanding of terms. The LDS do believe from OP single being and not made up of several beings

@depperm I mean, you could argue either way, I guess, but I'd argue LDS do believe in three divine persons that are one in a certain sense - just a different sense than the traditional trinitarians. So if you talk about trinitarians, a lot of the time LDS won't be included - but if you talk about unitarians/binitarians, they won't be included either most of the time.

@kutschkem I agree, from what I read I believed the LDS fit the description given and had defined doctrine on the subject. The OP did change right about when I posted but I had already posted. My answer says its LDS perspective

the potential of man to be like "god" is puts LDS into polytheism IMO

@TheChaz2.0 you are allowed your opinion

@Anne that first comment is full of non-sense (non LDS doctrine). Please don't attribute your understanding of LDS beliefs as actual LDS beliefs. There is no difference between the Holy Spirit and Holy Ghost (source). He is a member of the Godhead, just like Christ was before he came to earth.

Okay - second adjustment after removing first one. "The Father has a body of flesh and bones as tangible as man's; the Son also; but the Holy Ghost has not a body of flesh and bones, but is a personage of Spirit." (Doctrine & Covenants, 130:22) It is the LDS doctrine of a body being required to attain godhood that is an issue here, but as that is a different question, I will leave it at repeating that unitarianism is more akin to LDS views than trinitarianism, which agrees with your own comment, which I had upvoted.
